# SQL Вывод минимума

Tags: sql

Есть 4 таблицы; я уже объединил все таблицы, но не могу понять, как получить минимальный оклад, требуется вывод имени и оклада.

```
SELECT o.org_id, o.org_name, p.post_name, u.fio, e.oklad
FROM org o
INNER JOIN post p ON o.org_id = p.org_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.post_id = p.post_id
INNER JOIN emps e ON u.userid = e.userid
WHERE o.org_name = "ТПЦ2"
AND p.post_name = "СОРТИРОВЩИК"
```

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса непонятно, по какой выборке нужен минимум.
Кроме того, в зависимости от СУБД могут быть разные решения. Посмотрите, может быть здесь найдете ответ:
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function/page2.html

Answer (score 0):

добавить в конце 
and e.oklad = (select min(oklad) from emp)

Comment: И, скорее всего, вывод будет пустым, особенно, если  "СОРТИРОВЩИК" заменить на  "НАЧАЛЬНИК". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте сортировку

```
ORDER BY e.oklad ASC
```

И установите лимит на 1ю строку

```
LIMIT 1
```